# Is there any way to delimit minimum and maximum of an integer input range in PySimpleGui spinboxes, so that minimum doesn't surpases maximum?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

My objective is to input both a minimum value, and a maximum value, in a window in PySimpleGui using spinboxes.
But the idea is also to limit the range of the spinboxes according to each other, so that the minimum value doesn't surpass the maximum value; ex. if i input 50 in the upper spinbox (minimum) the lower one (maximum) should not be able to take a number below 50, or also similarly in reverse, if i input 60 in the lower spinbox (maximum), the upper one (minimum) should only accept a number below 60.

So far i have done this for the code for both spinboxes (setValues is a set with integers defined previously on the code).

```
minValues = int(min(setValues))
maxValues = int(max(setValues))
print(minValues, maxValues)

layout = [[sg.Spin([i for i in range(minValues,maxValues+1)], initial_value=minValues), sg.Text('Minimum value')],
        [sg.Spin([i for i in range(minValues,maxValues+1)], initial_value=maxValues), sg.Text('Maximum value')],
        [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
```

While preferably i would like a solution in PySimpleGui, an answer suggested in other GUI libraries would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update option `values` of another `sg.Spin` when event of this `sg.Spin`.

Demo code as following,

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

minValue = 5
maxValue = 20

layout = [
    [sg.Spin([i for i in range(minValue, maxValue)],     initial_value=minValue, size=(2, 1), enable_events=True, key='-MIN-'), sg.Text('Minimum value')],
    [sg.Spin([i for i in range(minValue+1, maxValue+1)], initial_value=maxValue, size=(2, 1), enable_events=True, key='-MAX-'), sg.Text('Maximum value')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

value_min, value_max = minValue, maxValue

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-MAX-':
        value_max = values[event]
        window['-MIN-'].update(values=[i for i in range(minValue, value_max)])
    elif event == '-MIN-':
        value_min = values[event]
        window['-MAX-'].update(values=[i for i in range(value_min+1, maxValue+1)])
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```